# Summernote font-family and color is not working

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, summernote

[image]

On selecting this works but color is not shown and looks ugly.

I have this code in my js file:

```
#= require jquery
#= require jquery-ui
#= require bootstrap/bootstrap-tooltip
#= require summernote

 $(document).ready ->
  $('#post_body').each ->
    $(this).summernote
      fontNames: ['Arial', 'Arial Black', 'Comic Sans MS', 'Courier New'],
      fontNamesIgnoreCheck: ['Arial', 'Arial Black', 'Comic Sans MS', 'Courier New']
      height: 250
      toolbar: [
          ['style', ['style']]
          ['font', ['bold', 'underline', 'clear']]
          ['fontname', ['fontname']]
          ['color', ['color']]
          ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']]
          ['table', ['table']]
          ['insert', ['link', 'picture', 'video']]
          ['view', ['fullscreen', 'codeview', 'help']]
  ]
```

In my Gemfile:

```
gem 'summernote-rails', '~> 0.8.1.1'
gem 'bootstrap-tooltip-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'font-awesome-sass-rails', '3.0.2.2'
```

In my css file, i have imported:

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "summernote";
@import "font-awesome";
```

And, another problem is like, when I select font-family it doesn't changes , it remains default 'sans-serif'

What might be the problem?? Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Check the references and clear duplicate references. I solve same problem by that way.

Comment: Can you add your sample code? It would be helpful to anyone who is getting the same problem. Thanks.

Comment: @user012 sorry for be late. There is not specific codes. but i can explain an example. On my project I gave references duplicate on master page and specific page. I had same problem which summernote modals (color-text options ...) was not working. After i  clear duplicate references problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Change to summernote-lite if you can.